# Given the coordinates of a circle and a point on it, its radius, and an angle, how do I find the coordinates of another point?

Tags: trigonometry, circles, coordinate-systems

I have a circle of radius R with coordinates (R<sub>x</sub>,R<sub>y</sub>). I also have a point on this circle with coordinates (A<sub>x</sub>,A<sub>y</sub>).

Given an angle N which separates A from B, how can I calculate (B<sub>x</sub>,B<sub>y</sub>)?

It doesn't matter which B I calculate, I need both.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm a little stumped to be honest. I should know how to do this. I've tried parametric equations but for some reason I just can't get my head around calculating between two points instead of calculating a single point.

Comment: Look up how to rotate about an arbitrary point on the plane (you can find a detailed explanation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803004/265466)). The point $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by rotating the latter about the circle’s center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (up to) two points $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by rotating it around the circle’s center: $$\begin{align}B_x &= R_x+(A_x-R_x)\cos(\pm N)-(A_y-R_y)\sin(\pm N) \\ B_y &= R_y+(A_x-R_x)\sin(\pm N)+(A_y-R_y)\cos(\pm N).\end{align}$$ Choose the sign of $N$ consistently throughout. You can find a detailed description of this rotation along with other methods to accomplish it in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1803004/265466).

Answer (score 0):

Recall that a circle can be described with the x-coordinate being $r\cos(\theta)$ and the y-coordinate $r\sin(\theta)$. You can use this to calculate the angle of A using inverse trig of the point. Once you get that angle, you can add the given angle N to this angle and then B will be given by $(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta)).$